# How can I send the update channel configuration request to the Orderer using node SDK?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-fabric-sdk-js

There are 03 main phases in the process of updating the channel configuration:

- (1) Get the latest configuration from the Orderer.
- (2) Modify the configuration.
- (3) Sign and send a transaction to the Orderer to update channel configuration.

I got an error at step (3) while trying to call `updateChannel()` function which is:

> { status: 'BAD_REQUEST',
>
> info: 'error authorizing update: error validating DeltaSet: policy for [Value]  /Channel/Orderer/BatchSize not satisfied: Failed to reach implicit threshold of 1 sub-policies, required 1 remaining' }

I followed the code from **hyperledger-sdk-node** repo about Channel update [here](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-sdk-node/blob/release-1.4/test/integration/configtxlator.js)

The policy of the Orderer of the network looks like this (I'm not sure about the problem I've got here)

```
# Policies defines the set of policies at this level of the config tree
# For Orderer policies, their canonical path is
#   /Channel/Orderer/<PolicyName>
Policies:
    Readers:
        Type: ImplicitMeta
        Rule: "ANY Readers"
    Writers:
        Type: ImplicitMeta
        Rule: "ANY Writers"
    Admins:
        Type: ImplicitMeta
        Rule: "MAJORITY Admins"
    # BlockValidation specifies what signatures must be included in the block
    # from the orderer for the peer to validate it.
    BlockValidation:
        Type: ImplicitMeta
        Rule: "ANY Writers"
```

More about the relevant code:

```
    let signatures = [];
    signatures.push(client.signChannelConfig(config_proto));


    let request = {
        name: channelName,
        // orderer: channel.getOrderer("orderer.example.com"), // Do I really need this?
        config: config_proto, // response from requesting configtxlator/compute
        txId: client.newTransactionID(),
        signatures: signatures
    };

    try {
        let result = await client.updateChannel(request); // ERROR HERE
        console.log("result", result);
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
```

If you need more information, just tell me! Any ideas should be helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to make this thing works!

In my case, I want to modify the `BatchSize` property of the orderer's configuration, which requires the signatures of a majority of the ordering organizations’ admins ([more detail](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.4/config_update.html#get-the-necessary-signatures)).

After the modification is completed, I need to sign the request by the orderer's admin.

The following code includes:

(1) Get the `key` and `certificate` of orderer's admin:

```
const keyPath = path.join(__dirname, '../../fabric/crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/example.com/users/Admin@example.com/msp/keystore');
const keyPEM = Buffer.from(readAllFiles(keyPath)[0]).toString();
const certPath = path.join(__dirname, '../../fabric/crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/example.com/users/Admin@example.com/msp/signcerts');
const certPEM = readAllFiles(certPath)[0];
```

(2) Assign signing identity to `client`:

```
client.setAdminSigningIdentity(keyPEM.toString(), certPEM.toString(), "OrdererMSP");
```

Now it's ready to be signed and send to orderer!

```
let signatures = [];
signatures.push(client.signChannelConfig(config_proto));

let request = {
    name: channelName,
    config: config_proto, // response from requesting configtxlator/compute
    txId: client.newTransactionID(),
    signatures: signatures
};

try {
    let result = await client.updateChannel(request);
    console.log("result", result);
} catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
}
```

readAllFiles function:

```
function readAllFiles(dir) {
    const files = fs.readdirSync(dir);
    const certs = [];
    files.forEach((file_name) => {
        const file_path = path.join(dir, file_name);
        logger.debug(' looking at file ::' + file_path);
        const data = fs.readFileSync(file_path);
        certs.push(data);
    });
    return certs;
}
```