# Hyperledger Fabric - Update a channel config by adding a new Org

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

I am trying to add a new Org to an existing Hyperledger fabric network.

The initial network is created by the byfn.sh script that stands up an Orderer and Org1 & Org2.

I have followed this [example](https://medium.com/@kctheservant/add-a-new-organization-on-existing-hyperledger-fabric-network-2c9e303955b2) on Medium.com to create the update protobuf file. Everything that requires configtxgen, cryptogen and configtxlator is done as per this example. However, when it comes to executing the command `peer channel signconfigtx -f org3_update_in_envelope.pb`, I would like to do that using the Fabric Node SDK.

A point to note here is that if I execute the `peer channel ...` commands from the cli container command line, the channel update goes through, so I know that the file org3_update_in_envelope.pb is not corrupted.

Using this [tutorial](https://hyperledger.github.io/fabric-sdk-node/release-1.4/tutorial-channel-create.html) and some guidance from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55416155/how-can-i-send-the-update-channel-configuration-request-to-the-orderer-using-nod), I have the following code:

```
 let envelope_pb_file_name = '/tmp/' + json.msp + '_update_in_envelope.pb'; // the pb file we create using command line
        let envelope_bytes = fs.readFileSync(envelope_pb_file_name);

        if (envelope_bytes === undefined) {
            throw new Error(`Could not read the protobuffer file ${envelope_pb_file_name}. Error`);
        }
        // have the nodeSDK extract out the config update
        let config_update = client.extractChannelConfig(envelope_bytes);
        let signature = client.signChannelConfig(config_update);
        let signatures = [];
        signatures.push(signature);
        //let orderers = this.loanNetwork.getChannel().getOrderers();
        let orderer, ordererName = "orderer.example.com:7050";
        const ORDERER_URL = 'grpcs://localhost:7050';
        const data = fs.readFileSync(SyndLoanConfig.chainconfig.networkpath + '/crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/example.com/tlsca/tlsca.example.com-cert.pem').toString();

            orderer = client.newOrderer(ORDERER_URL,
            {
                'pem': Buffer.from(data).toString(),
                'ssl-target-name-override': 'orderer.example.com'
            });

        let mspId = client.getMspid(); // mspId shows "OrdererMSP" after this call is executed

        const keyPath = SyndLoanConfig.chainconfig.networkpath + '/crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/example.com/users/Admin@example.com/msp/keystore';
        let keyFile, keyFileAry = fs.readdirSync(keyPath).filter(fn => fn.endsWith('_sk'));

        for (let f of keyFileAry) {
            keyFile = f;
            break;

        }

        keyFile = path.join(keyPath,keyFile);
        const keyPEM = fs.readFileSync(keyFile).toString();

        const certPath = SyndLoanConfig.chainconfig.networkpath + '/crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/example.com/users/Admin@example.com/msp/signcerts';
        let certFile, certFileAry = fs.readdirSync(certPath).filter(fn => fn.endsWith('.pem'));

        for (let f of certFileAry) {
            certFile = f;
            break;

        }
        certFile = path.join(certPath,certFile);
        const certPEM = fs.readFileSync(certFile).toString();

        client.setAdminSigningIdentity(keyPEM, certPEM, "OrdererMSP");

        if (orderer === undefined) {
            throw new Error(`Could not find an orderer associated with channel ${orgJSON.channel}. Error.`)
        }

        let tx_id = client.newTransactionID();
        let request = {
            config: config_update, //the binary config
            // envelope: envelope_bytes,
            signatures: signatures, // the collected signatures
            name: orgJSON.channel, // the channel name
            orderer: orderer, //the orderer from above
            txId: tx_id //the generated transaction id
        };

        let addOrgResult = await client.updateChannel(request);
```

addOrgResult variable shows the following error:

```
info: implicit policy evaluation failed - 0 sub-policies were satisfied, but this policy requires 1 of the 'Writers' sub-policies to be satisfied: permission denied     
status: FORBIDDEN
```

Orderer logs show this:

```
2020-01-17 21:49:21.620 UTC [cauthdsl] deduplicate -> ERRO 057 Principal deserialization failure (MSP  is unknown) for identity 0
 2020-01-17 21:49:21.621 UTC [cauthdsl] deduplicate -> ERRO 058 Principal deserialization failure (MSP  is unknown) for identity 0
 2020-01-17 21:49:21.621 UTC [cauthdsl] deduplicate -> ERRO 059 Principal deserialization failure (MSP  is unknown) for identity 0
 2020-01-17 21:49:21.621 UTC [orderer.common.broadcast] ProcessMessage -> WARN 05a [channel: mychannel] Rejecting broadcast of config message from 192.168.208.1:56556 because of error: implicit policy evaluation failed - 0 sub-policies were satisfied, but this policy requires 1 of the 'Writers' sub-policies to be satisfied: permission denied
```

Going through Nikhil Gupta's helpful response to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57662562/when-i-try-to-create-a-channel-using-hyperledger-fabric-the-request-fails), it appears that this error is due to

> The error before the policy warning, ERRO 021 Principal
>   deserialization failure (MSP SampleOrg is unknown) for identity 0,
>   indicates that the MSP ID that was passed as a parameter with the
>   request was not recognized by the ordering service. This could be a
>   result of passing the wrong MSP ID to the command. This error may also
>   indicate that your organization has not joined the consortium hosted
>   by the ordering service system channel. If you are updating an
>   application channel, this error could occur if your organization is
>   not yet a member of the channel you are trying to update.

However, I am not sure how to proceed because I have connected to the network (Gateway.connect) using the `Admin@example.com identity`. Additionally, I am also calling `client.setAdminSigningIdentity(keyPEM, certPEM, "OrdererMSP");` before making the update.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default policy for updating a channel requires a majority, which in your case means you will need signatures from both Org1 admin and Org2 admin and then either Org1 or Org2 can send the actual config update to the orderer.

This means that you need to run

```
let config_update = client.extractChannelConfig(envelope_bytes);
let signature = client.signChannelConfig(config_update);
let signatures = [];
signatures.push(signature);
```

as both an Org1 admin and an Org2 admin.

You can then submit the transaction to the orderer as either an Org1 admin or an Org2 admin (but not as the Orderer admin).

Comment: Thanks Gari. I will update my code using your info. I will update here once I have resolved the error I am getting now.

Comment: It worked now. Thanks for all your help. I got a success message back in the Client.updateChannel call.